# Does having a zero eigenvalue preclude a matrix from being indefinite?

Tags: linear-algebra, analysis, multivariable-calculus, optimization, nonlinear-optimization

If a $3\times3$ matrix has a positive eigenvalue, a negative eigenvalue, and a zero eigenvalue, is it then, by definition, indefinite? I think so, since the matrix has both a positive and a negative eigenvalue. However, my optimisation lecture notes categorically claims that as a long as there is any zero eigenvalue, the stationary-point test fails.

I am not including the details of the stationary-point test as it is tangential to the substance of my question.

Comment: So, where is the contradiction which is bothering you?

Answer (score 2):

If matrix $A$ has both positive and negative eigenvalues, then we have $A v_1 = \lambda_1 v_1$ and $A v_2 = \lambda_2 v_2$ with eigenvalues $\lambda_1 > 0 > \lambda_2$ and corresponding eigenvectors $v_1$ and $v_2$. Thus we have $v_1^T A v_1 = \lambda_1 ||v_1||^2 > 0 > \lambda_2 ||v_2||^2 = v_2^T A v_2$. Which implies that A is an indefinite matrix.

Comment: The crucial detail here is whether having a zero eigenvalue (in addition to having a positive and a negative eigenvalue) precludes the matrix from being indefinite.  To repeat: If a 3×3 matrix has a positive eigenvalue, a negative eigenvalue, **as well as a zero eigenvalue**, is it indefinite?

Comment: It does not have any impact here. According to the definition (http://mathworld.wolfram.com/IndefiniteMatrix.html) there must exist two non-zero vectors which give positive and negative values. In this case we do have such vectors: $v_1$ and $v_2$.

Answer (score 1):

If the matrix is $2\times 2$ then having a zero eigenvalue stops it being indefinite, though not in an interesting way.

A $2\times 2$ matrix has only two eigenvalues, so if one is zero it is not possible for one to be positive and one to be negative.